# Excel Macro requiring a click in the field to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VERY simple macro to convert text dates to actual date fields in excel.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
' fixdates
'

'
    Range("AM2:AM5,AJ2:AK5").Select
    Range("AJ2").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
    Range("AJ4").Select
End Sub
```

BUT whenever I run it I have to actually click in each cell in order for it to convert properly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need `TextToColumns` so it is no longer text. If the data is text, you can't use `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your subroutine to set the values to be the values.  That will force the text string that looks like a date to be converted to the actual date:

```
Sub Macro2()
    With Range("AM2:AM5,AJ2:AK5")
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```